# I want to make my android application responsive

Tags: android, user-interface, responsive-design

My app is having maximum 20-25 screens. Should I use dynamic sizes units like dp or sp or do I have to make 3 different layouts with different sizes for each screen. which method would be best or is there any other way to achieve responsiveness?

I have tried with sp units it is working good at some levels. But not fully responsive.

Comment: mdp and sdp?  Those aren't things.  There's dp and sp, for physical units (1dp = 1/160th inch) and scaled text (scales by system UI setting).  But very few things should be set numericaly-  most things are set by the size of the content and the location on the screen relative to other elements

Comment: You can use a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) to design a flexible layout that works on multiple similarly sized screens - although sometimes an alternate layout for a tablet-sized screen may be needed. Setting absolute sizes for views is usually not necessary when using layout containers like ConstraintLayout (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

You can do different layouts for different screen sizes or you can use guidelines and helpers within Constraint Layout .
I followed this video for my app and it worked great.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lSQcJjZPFs&ab_channel=PhilippLackner